# unable to return json from django view to axios

Tags: django, django-views, frontend, axios, backend

I want to make a Visual search interface with keywords and category to search sth. Obviously, It needs front-end and back-end data interaction. So after weighing some tools, I have choosed **Vue** and **axios** to implement data interaction in the **front-end**, and **django view** in the **front-end**.

In my index.html page, I defined my axios like this.

```
var param = new URLSearchParams();
param.append('searchKey',this.searchKey);
param.append('category',this.selected);

axios.post("{% url 'main:getCommodityInfo'%}",
             param,
            {headers:{'X-CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken')}},)
     .then(response=>{
           console.log(response);
      })
     .catch(error=>{
           console.log(error);
           alert("connection has error")
      })
```

**searchKey** and **category** could be acquired by Vue object. Then I post the data to my back-end django view.

```
def getCommodityInfo(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # To get the POST paramaters
        searchKey = request.POST.get('searchKey')
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        # unique ID for each record for DB
        uniqueId = str(uuid4())
        print("Enter the view!  ",searchKey,category)
        # set setting
        settings = {
            'unique_id': uniqueId,  
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
        }
        # task Id to indentify each spider task
        task = scrapyd.schedule('JDSpider', 'getCommodityInfo',
                                settings=settings, searchKey=searchKey, category=category)

        print("It seems everything is running well? ")
        print(task,uniqueId)
        print("-"*100)
        return JsonResponse({'taskId': task, 'uniqueId': uniqueId, 'status': 'started'},safe=False)
```

Well, the view could acutally get the POST paramaters. ***But When I am trying to return the status json from view to the axios function, error occurs.***

```
[20/Mar/2019 21:03:08] "GET /main/ HTTP/1.1" 200 7216
[20/Mar/2019 21:03:08] "GET /static/main/axios.min.js HTTP/1.1" 304 0
[20/Mar/2019 21:03:08] "GET /static/main/axios.min.map HTTP/1.1" 304 0
Enter the view!   switch Electronics
[20/Mar/2019 21:03:30] "GET /main/?searchKey=switch&category=Electronics HTTP/1.1" 200 7216
It seems everything is running well? 
8fdcee984b1011e9b7e5ace010528bab e07cd1ee-efe8-4c23-8457-51732aa57435
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[20/Mar/2019 21:03:33] "POST /main/getCommodityInfo/ HTTP/1.1" 200 119
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] The software in your host has aborted an established connection.
[20/Mar/2019 21:03:33] "POST /main/getCommodityInfo/ HTTP/1.1" 500 59
----------------------------------------
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 11890)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 138, in run
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 332, in send_headers
    self.send_preamble()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 255, in send_preamble
    ('Date: %s\r\n' % format_date_time(time.time())).encode('iso-8859-1')
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 453, in _write
    result = self.stdout.write(data)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\socketserver.py", line 775, in write
    self._sock.sendall(b)
ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] The software in your host has aborted an established connection.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 141, in run
    self.handle_error()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 86, in handle_error
    super().handle_error()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 368, in handle_error
    self.finish_response()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 180, in finish_response
    self.write(data)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 274, in write
    self.send_headers()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 331, in send_headers
    if not self.origin_server or self.client_is_modern():
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 344, in client_is_modern
    return self.environ['SERVER_PROTOCOL'].upper() != 'HTTP/0.9'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\socketserver.py", line 639, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\socketserver.py", line 361, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\socketserver.py", line 696, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\site-packages\django\core\servers\basehttp.py", line 154, in handle
    handler.run(self.server.get_app())
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\handlers.py", line 144, in run
    self.close()
  File "D:\Anacaonda\lib\wsgiref\simple_server.py", line 35, in close
    self.status.split(' ',1)[0], self.bytes_sent
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

I have tried to debug the process, but the code logic is too complicated to understand. ***I could only find the errors happens when executing***

```
return JsonResponse({'taskId': task, 'uniqueId': uniqueId, 'status': 'started'},safe=False)
```

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

---

I' ve looked around and apparently I've got the choice below.

```
<form  action="{%url 'main:getCommodityInfo'%}" method="POST">
```

Using the form could get the json from the django View after my test. But I don't want to use it in my project instead of axios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stacktrace you are getting is a known bug of the `wsgiref BaseHandler` on Windows.

You can keep track of it here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/9713

and here:

https://bugs.python.org/issue27682

Comment: Thx. It works. However there is a further problem after fixing the error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55274380/axios-unable-to-get-json-from-django-view
Could you check it ?