# Axios unable to get JSON from Django view

Tags: django, django-views, axios, django-urls

I want to implement a front-end and back-end data interaction with axios and django view. Now I have succeed in posting data to django view with code below.

```
axios.post("{% url 'main:getCommodityInfo'%}",
                        param,
                        {headers:{'X-CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken')}})
                .then(response=>{
                  console.log(response);
                  alert("response has been caught");
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                  console.log(error);
                  alert("connection has error")
                })
```

But when I want to return json from view to axios:

```
def getCommodityInfo(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        # get POST parameters
        searchKey = request.POST.get('searchKey')
        category = request.POST.get('category')
        print("Enter the POST view!  ", searchKey, category)
        # unique ID for each record for DB
        uniqueId = str(uuid4())
        # spider setting
        settings = {
            'unique_id': uniqueId,
            'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)'
        }
        # taskId to indentify each task
        task = scrapyd.schedule('JDSpider', 'getCommodityInfo',
                                settings=settings, searchKey=searchKey, category=category)

        print("It seems everything is running well? ")
        return JsonResponse({'taskId': task, 'uniqueId': uniqueId, 'status': 'started'},safe=False)
```

the browser has no change! Firstly, I tried to figure out why it occurred independently. **The potential clue maybe lie in urls.py.**

```
urlpatterns = [
    # eg:127.0.0.1:8000/main/
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('getCommodityInfo/',views.getCommodityInfo, name = 'getCommodityInfo'),
    path('getCommodityCommentDetail/',views.getCommodityCommentDetail, name="getCommodityCommentDetail"),
    path('commodityInfo/<str:category>/<str:searchKey>/',views.commodityInfoPage, name = 'commodityInfoPage'),
    path('commentsInfo/<str:commodityId>/',views.commodityCommentPage,name = 'commodityCommentPage'),
    # path('?searchkey=<str:searchKey>&categroy=<str:category>/',views.getCommodityInfo, name = 'getCommodityInfo'),
]
```

Because I found that the initial **url** `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/` in my browser after clicking on the button to post data to **getCommodityInfo** view became `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/?searchKey=switch&category=Electronics` . This url seems not to match any url patterns in **urls.py**. So I tried to append an additional urlpattern `path('?searchkey=<str:searchKey>&categroy=<str:category>/',views.getCommodityInfo, name = 'getCommodityInfo')`. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

After that, I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please tell me whether my idea to solve right. Or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

---

**Edit 1**  **My console logs were asked.**

This is my console log after click the button to post data.

[image: This is my console log after click the button to post data]

And when I click on the alert, the browser go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/main/?searchKey=switch&category=Electronics` and the chrome network loading shows like:

[image]

And there are no log output in console.

---

**Edit 2**  **There are some doubts on whether axios send the request by POST or GET, and I try to indentify it in my django view**

My python console output this, meaning **getCommodityInfo** did indentify the request as POST(You could review my code)

[image]

---

**Edit 3**  **@dirkgroten pointed out likely I have sended both POST and GET. So I give the whole code related in my template**

And here is my form. And whole js related.

```
<form action="" id="searchForm">
<label for="searchKey">KeyWords</label>
<input v-model="searchKey" palceholder="Input Search Key" type="string" class="form-control" id="searchKey" name="searchKey">
<label for="category">Commodity Category</label>
<select v-model="selected" id="category" name="category">
    <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
        ${option.text}
    </option>
</select>

<button v-on:click="startSpider"  class="btn btn-default" >Submit</button>
<p>KeyWords : ${ searchKey }</p>
<p>Category : ${ selected }</p>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var searchApp = new Vue({
        delimiters:['${','}'],
        el: "#searchForm",
        data:{
          searchKey:'',
          selected:'',
          options: [
            {text: 'Baby', value:'Baby'},
            {text: 'Book', value:'Book'},
            {text: 'Electronics', value:'Electronics'},
            {text: 'Fashion', value:'Fashion'},
            {text: 'Food', value:'Food'},
            {text: 'Health&Beauty', value:'Health&Beauty'},
            {text: 'Home', value:'Home'},
            {text: 'Industrial&Scientific', value:'Industrial&Scientific'},
            {text: 'Motor', value:'Motor'},
            {text: 'Pet', value:'Pet'},
            {text: 'Sports', value:'Sports'},
            {text: 'Other', value:'Other'},
          ]
        },
        created:function(){
          this.selected = "";
        },
        methods:{
          startSpider:function(event){
            console.log(this.searchKey);
            console.log(this.selected);
            alert("spider is ready to run!");
            var param = new URLSearchParams();
            param.append('searchKey',this.searchKey);
            param.append('category',this.selected);

            axios.post("{% url 'main:getCommodityInfo'%}",
                        param,
                        {headers:{'X-CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken')}})
                .then(response=>{
                  this.searchKey = "!!!";
                  this.category = "Baby";
                  console.log(response.data)
                  alert("response has been caught");
                  console.log(response.data)
                })
                .catch(error=>{
                  console.log(error);
                  alert("connection has error")
                })
          },
          getCookie:function(name) {
              var value = '; ' + document.cookie
              var parts = value.split('; ' + name + '=')
              if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(';').shift()
            },
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: please paste console logs of your browser

Comment: @Nakul Narayanan I have edited my question.

Comment: you are sending a GET request instead of POST

Comment: Actually, the django view does indentify the axios request as POST. So the GET request is what? From the django view 'return JsonResponse' ?

Comment: from the console log image that you posted its clearly known as it is GET request

Comment: @Nakul Narayanan Well, maybe there are some misunderstanding between us, you could check my lastest update of question

Comment: You’re sending both a POST and a GET. Before the POST returns there’s also a GET according to your python console. Check your javascript code. What’s the button that triggers the axios call? Could it be that it’s submitting the form as well? If it’s a “submit” button in a form you should prevent default behavior in your javascript.

Comment: @dirkgroten Thx for your advice. I have checked my javascript code, but due to my limmited experience on Vue, no apparent bugs found. So I have posted the whole code, could you help me to check it?

Answer (score 0):

Acutally, I have found the mistake. It's all about the `<form>`... The solution is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55690356/axios-post-automatically-splice-url-with-my-params)