# axios.post automatically splice url with my params

Tags: vue.js, axios

I want to implement an api with vue and axios in my front-end:

```
methods:{
  startSpider:function(event){
    alert("spider is ready to run!");

    let data = {'searchKey':this.searchKey,
            'category':this.category,
            'num':this.num};
    axios.post("{% url 'main:getCommodityInfo'%}",
                data,
                {headers:{'X-CSRFToken': this.getCookie('csrftoken')}})
        .then(response=>{
          console.log(response.data)
        })
        .catch(error=>{
          console.log(error);
          alert("connection has error")
        })
  },
```

When I call this function, I expect to get data from the back-end and stay at the inital url. It does receive data but the url quickly changed.

After some exploration, I find the browser implement two request! First, POST, and next GET:

Using **'searchKey':'switch', 'category':'electronic','num':60** as an example.
[image]

and My browser url subsequently changes to 
[image]

Why it happens? I have just used POST not GET. The axios post seems to automatically splice inital url with the params. I have tried a lot of ways but failed. Even I have writed a small demo with the similiar structure like this to test, but the demo runs well! What happened? Help me please...

---

Updated I: Give my server behavior(django-view) and my router related is `path('getCommodityInfo/',views.getCommodityInfo, name = 'getCommodityInfo')`

```
def getCommodityInfo(request):
    print(request.body)
    return JsonResponse({"data":True}, safe=False)
```

---

Updated II: Give my front-end form:

```
                <form>
                    <label for="searchKey">KeyWords</label>
                    <input v-model="searchKey" placeholder="Input Search Key" type="string" class="form-control" id="searchKey" name="searchKey">

                    <label for="category">Commodity Category</label>
                    <select v-model="selected" id="category" name="category">
                        <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
                            ${option.text}
                        </option>
                    </select>
                    <br>
                    <label for="num">Amount</label>
                    <input v-model="num" placeholder="Input amount needed" type="string" class="form-control" id="num" name="num" >
                    <button v-on:click="startSpider"  class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                    <p>KeyWords : ${ searchKey }</p>
                    <p>Category : ${ selected }</p>
                    <p>Amount: ${ num }</p>
                </form>
```

Comment: Are you sure your server doesn't redirect to this GET url in response to this POST request? You can check response headers for POST request in the browser's developer console.

Comment: I uses simpliest server behavior to test. You could check my update.

Comment: Show response headers for first POST request, please

Comment: @Styx Thx. I have found my mistake. You could check my lastest update. I ignored to set the button type, so the button default will be submmit button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug happened because of not setting button type. 
We could check [this](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#attr-button-type):

> The missing value default is the Submit Button state.

And in the front-end form there is no type for the button, so the button type will be submmit button. When click on the button, it will automatically send a get request.

Modify the button like this:

```
<button v-on:click="startSpider"  class="btn btn-default" type='button'>Submit</button>
```